# Only Selecting Specific Row Info From One Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, row, greatest-n-per-group, ssms

Okay so I'm having some serious trouble with this one

I have the original query (which is query A in this one below) that selects all info (including null) from `SiteAppointmentArrivals` which is awesome - because I need to display when users do not arrive at their designated Site - No Shows.

However, these sites are all grouped in separate groups.  So one group could have five sites, another might only have 1, etc. and sometimes when a user signs into a Grouped Site, they'll only sign into one site - when logically they should be signed into all sites - but in the system it's currently showing them signed into one site and the others as NULL.

Now ontop of this I also just want to select just one Site in each group (hence the `max(s.siteid)` which works fine for people who sign into all the sites or do not show up at all to any.  However, for those odd one's where they have arrival dates and nulls - two rows show up.  I want to eliminate the NULL row in this instance since, they logically signed into the Group by signing into one of the sites.

I created this pseudo code - trying to combine two versions of the query - one with all info and one with info of only arrived people.

If a GroupID from A (all info) is found in B (only arrived info) then display B row of info, if GroupID in  A is not in B then display A row.  I feel to logic would appropriately capture what I need but I'm just no sure how to express it in SQL

**Edited for Simplicity**

```
Select DISTINCT
CASE WHEN a.GroupID=b.GroupID THEN b.*
WHEN a.GroupID <> b.GroupID THEN a.* END -- Psuedo Code
From
(SELECT DISTINCT
    max(s.SiteID) SiteID,
    s.GroupID,
    saa.Time ArrivalTime,
    sas.ScannerUserID
FROM 
    dbo.Sites s
    INNER JOIN dbo.SiteAppointments sa ON s.SiteID = sa.SiteID
    INNER JOIN dbo.SiteAppointmentsScanners sas ON sa.SiteAppointmentID = sas.SiteAppointmentID
    LEFT JOIN dbo.SiteAppointmentArrivals saa ON sa.SiteAppointmentID = saa.SiteAppointmentId 
                                          AND saa.ScannerUserID = sas.ScannerUserID
WHERE 
    ProjectID = 110
    AND 
        (
            (CAST(sa.StartDateTime AS DATE) >= '09/03/2014' AND CAST(sa.StartDateTime AS DATE) <= '09/03/2014')
            OR
            (CAST(sa.EndDateTime AS DATE) >= '09/03/2014' AND CAST(sa.EndDateTime AS DATE) <= '09/03/2014')
        )
    AND ((CAST(saa.Date AS DATE) >= '09/03/2014' AND CAST(saa.Date AS DATE) <= '09/03/2014') OR saa.Date IS NULL)
GROUP BY
    s.GroupID,
    saa.Time,
    sas.ScannerUserID
 )a

LEFT JOIN 


(SELECT DISTINCT
    max(s.SiteID) SiteID,
    s.GroupID,
    saa.Time ArrivalTime,
    sas.ScannerUserID
FROM 
    dbo.Sites s
    INNER JOIN dbo.SiteAppointments sa ON s.SiteID = sa.SiteID
    INNER JOIN dbo.SiteAppointmentsScanners sas ON sa.SiteAppointmentID = sas.SiteAppointmentID
    INNER JOIN dbo.SiteAppointmentArrivals saa ON sa.SiteAppointmentID = saa.SiteAppointmentId 
                                          AND saa.ScannerUserID = sas.ScannerUserID
WHERE 
    ProjectID = 110
    AND 
        (
            (CAST(sa.StartDateTime AS DATE) >= '09/03/2014' AND CAST(sa.StartDateTime AS DATE) <= '09/03/2014')
            OR
            (CAST(sa.EndDateTime AS DATE) >= '09/03/2014' AND CAST(sa.EndDateTime AS DATE) <= '09/03/2014')
    )
    AND ((CAST(saa.Date AS DATE) >= '09/03/2014' AND CAST(saa.Date AS DATE) <= '09/03/2014') OR saa.Date IS NULL)
GROUP BY
    s.GroupID,
    saa.Time,
    sas.ScannerUserID
 ) b ON a.SiteID=b.SiteID
```

An example as well:

```
SiteID | GroupID | ArrivalTime             | Scanner
------------------------------------------------------
12345  | 54321   | NULL                    | 1011
------------------------------------------------------
67890  | 54321   | 2014-09-03 09:09:48.053 | 1011
```

So here - a Scanner/user has arrived into the site within a Group (so technically he's signed into the group even though the other site is NULL) so I would like to hide the NULL value and just keep the Arrival value.

Comment: to select columns from either one table or another it is better to use UNION ALL. You need to construct two separate queries correctly though (i.e. use `where not exists` clauses in each to make sure they do not show duplicate information). As for your query: please make it smaller and provide some sample data. It is in its current form is TL;DR

Comment: if you really want a solution for your problem, try to regenerate the problem with less code and some sample data and desired output and your attempt. Not many people will be willing to help you with this wall of code :)

Comment: Thanks for the info guys - updated the query to just show the bare essentials (and still produce the same issue)

Comment: Also added in an example for clarity

Comment: Please add some sample data, current output and expected output for clarity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to use ROW_NUMBER() ranking function:

```
WITH SiteArrivals AS (
SELECT DISTINCT
    s.SiteID,
    s.GroupID,
    saa.Time ArrivalTime,
    sas.ScannerUserID,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY s.GroupID ORDER BY saa.Time DESC, s.SiteID DESC) rn
FROM 
    dbo.Sites s
    INNER JOIN dbo.SiteAppointments sa ON s.SiteID = sa.SiteID
    INNER JOIN dbo.SiteAppointmentsScanners sas ON sa.SiteAppointmentID = sas.SiteAppointmentID
    LEFT JOIN dbo.SiteAppointmentArrivals saa ON sa.SiteAppointmentID = saa.SiteAppointmentId 
                                          AND saa.ScannerUserID = sas.ScannerUserID )
SELECT * 
FROM SiteArrivals sa WHERE SiteID IS NOT NULL and rn = 1
```

Here is a SqlFiddle that demonstrates this solution - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b57c6/4

Comment: This is strange - I get an "Ambiguous column name 'SiteID'" in Line 7 error when trying to run this (I'm not sure why either since S.SIteID is there and removing the SiteID name next to it still produces the error.

Comment: Updated the answer, it was missing aliases and you have SiteID it two tables.

Comment: Actually this looks super close to what I'm looking for - the only issue I'm getting is that it looks like it's selecting the "NULL" value of the group rather than the Arrived Value.  If the entire group is NULL in the ArrivalTime then it's fine to pull a NULL value however, if there is a Not Null value in the group then it should only select the Not Null Value.

Comment: I have updated the answer to get the record with max ArrivalTime, and if all are NULL get record with max SiteID

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, you simply need to "copy" the arrival time to those rows, where the Scanner / user is the same and the GroupID is the same, but SiteID is different and ArrivalTime not specified.

In this case you can simply use the following query:

```
;
with f1 as
(
    SELECT DISTINCT
        max(s.SiteID) SiteID,
        s.GroupID,
        saa.Time ArrivalTime,
        sas.ScannerUserID
    FROM dbo.Sites s
    INNER JOIN dbo.SiteAppointments sa
        ON s.SiteID = sa.SiteID
    INNER JOIN dbo.SiteAppointmentsScanners sas
        ON sa.SiteAppointmentID = sas.SiteAppointmentID
    LEFT JOIN dbo.SiteAppointmentArrivals saa
        ON sa.SiteAppointmentID = saa.SiteAppointmentId 
        AND saa.ScannerUserID = sas.ScannerUserID
    WHERE 
        ProjectID = 110
        AND 
            (
                (CAST(sa.StartDateTime AS DATE) >= '09/03/2014' AND CAST(sa.StartDateTime AS DATE) <= '09/03/2014')
                OR
                (CAST(sa.EndDateTime AS DATE) >= '09/03/2014' AND CAST(sa.EndDateTime AS DATE) <= '09/03/2014')
            )
        AND ((CAST(saa.Date AS DATE) >= '09/03/2014' AND CAST(saa.Date AS DATE) <= '09/03/2014') OR saa.Date IS NULL)
    GROUP BY
        s.GroupID,
        saa.Time,
        sas.ScannerUserID
 ),
 f2 as
 (
    select GroupID, ScannerUserID, max(ArrivalTime) ArrivalTime
    from f1
    group by GroupID, ScannerUserID
 )
 select f1.SiteID, f1.GroupID, f2.ArrivalTime, f1.ScannerUserID
 from f1 f1
 left join f2 f2
    on f1.GroupID = f2.GroupID
    and f1.ScannerUserID = f2.ScannerUserID
```

SqlFiddle that demonstrates this solution can be found here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/623b2c/10

Comment: This WOULD work - but I noticed in the Select you had GroupID listed twice rather than GroupID, SiteID... - having just the GroupID would fix the issue but I need to show both the SiteID and GroupID - and though the Group will be the same the SiteIDs will be different. SO it produces two lines of similar info (minus the different SiteID) - which I just want to eliminate to produce one site associated with one group. (Hopefully that makes sense lol)

Comment: Actually I noticed that for the NULL values that produce the "double row of info" - it just replicating the Arrival info into the Null row - when I add the SiteID

Comment: According to ***`SiteID`*** and double ***`GoupID`*** - it was a simple typo. Sure, this might be ***`SiteID`***. And this will copy the arrival time from the site ID where the Group ID is specified to those ones, where it's missing... Among this, in case of existance of the ***`SiteID`*** with no ***`GroupID`*** the changed query will return the correct info. If you want to 'hide' sites which have not ***`GroupID`*** simply replace `left join` by `inner join`